# Point me in the right direction to build a random quote generator in React without repeating a quote

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to return a new quote on each onClick without repeating a quote.

To do that I'll keep track of the quotes array in state and each time handleClick() is triggered, splice the quote out of the quotes array and return the new array as state. When the quotes array's length is < 1, I reset the state property of the quotes array to a new copy of quotes.

However this brings up another problem. A quote could potentially repeat when it is the last quote in the array and the first quote in the new array.

```
class QuoteMachine extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
  copy: props.quotes.slice(),
  author: fullQuote[0],
  quote: fullQuote[1],
}
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(){ 
  const copy = this.props.quotes.slice();
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
  const newCopy = (this.state.copy.length > 1) ? copy.splice(index,1) : 
copy;
  const item = copy[index];
this.setState({
  author: item[0],
  quote: item[1],
  copy: newCopy
})
  }

  render(){

return (
  <div id='quote-box'>

    <div id='text'><h1> {this.state.author} </h1></div>

    <div id='author'><h3> {this.state.quote} </h3></div>

    <button onClick={this.handleClick} id='new-quote'>New 
Quote</button>
        <a id='tweet-quote' 
href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet">Tweet 
Me</a>
      </div>
      )
    } 
}
const QUOTES = [
    ["Stay Hungry. Stay Foolish.", "Steve Jobs"],
    ["Good Artists Copy, Great Artists Steal.", "Pablo Picasso"],
    ["Argue with idiots, and you become an idiot.", "Paul Graham"],
    ["Be yourself; everyone else is already taken.", "Oscar Wilde"],
    ["Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication.", "Leonardo Da Vinci"]
  ];
const fullQuote = QUOTES[Math.floor(Math.random() * QUOTES.length)]
ReactDOM.render(<QuoteMachine quotes={QUOTES} />, 
            document.getElementById('node'))
```

Edit: So I took your advice to just compare two quotes together and changed the handleClick() method to this:

```
handleClick(){ 
  let copy = this.props.quotes.slice();
  let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
this.setState(function(prevState,props){
  if(prevState.quote != copy[index]){
    return {quote: copy[index]}
  }return {quote: copy[index+1]}
})
```

}

This returns a new quote on each click event but a new problem popped up as I kept clicking the button: Eventually the entire UI disappears when I click enough times. I'm thoroughly confused as to why this happened.

Comment: if thats all you want to do you can just pull a random quote and keep track of the last one read and compare on demand.  no need for a second array

Comment: Not sure if there's a question. The problem you mention is more an issue with the design of your algorithm and data structure than anything to do with react. Why not keep the full array and build an array of indexes "used" then when it "runs out" just select the new index before clearing the old indexes array so you can check it's not the same as the last one.

Comment: Hey guys please check out my edit. I updated my handleClick() but a new problem popped up.